# How to get the second expression from the first one?

Tags: taylor-expansion, rational-numbers, binomial-distribution

I have the following expression

$(I_2)^{\frac{1}{2}}(1 - \displaystyle\frac{b I_3}{(I_2)^{3/2}})^{\frac{1}{3}}$

for which $I_2$ is always positive (the only constraint that I have).

I would like to know how can I reach the following expression:

$((I_2)^\frac{3}{2} - b I_3)^{\frac{1}{3}}$

I have found the above equality in a scientific paper.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I really didn't know which tags to include

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is $$\frac{I_2^{1/2}\left(I_2^{3/2}-bI_3\right)^{1/3}}{\left(I_2^{3/2}\right)^{1/3}}$$ and you can cancel $I_2$

Comment: Easy right? I didn't think about it.

Comment: Is your problem solved now? If so, i wish you a nice day!

Comment: Yes thanks, But just one question. How the power of I2, which is 2/3, is changed to 3/2?

Comment: I thought the power $$(I_2)^{2/3}$$ is a typo

Comment: Yes, Yes. You are right. It was a typo. The question is edited. Thanks and have a nice day.

Comment: Have a nice day too!